# Should a temple always be built on turn 2 in Antike?

Tags: openings, antike

I played my first game of **Antike** with 5 other people.  Everyone but me started at Marble, then paid one resource on the next turn to jump to Temple.  Having never played before, I went another way, just to be different.

Getting a temple built on turn 2 obviously kick-starts your economy, but is it really the best way to start?  Did everyone know something I didn't or were they all just mirroring each other?

FWIW, I went Gold-Arming-Know How and claimed the first VP on turn 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While getting a Temple is a very good first move, there's a lot to be said for getting the first Technology.
I would immediately follow it up with a Temple though.